# Query to find all stored procedures which have used cursor or while loop

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, while-loop, cursor

I know how Stack overflow works but I do not have data or SQL scripts to post my findings.

I googled a lot but could not find what I am looking for.

Is it possible to have SQL script where I can find list of stored procedures or functions in my DB which have used cursor or while loop so that I can change them to SET based statements?

Also, if possible can I know which stored procedures have used dynamic query?

I do not want to go and check each stored procedure manually, so looking for some automated approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi! Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

If your SPs and other objects are not encrypeted you might try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%EXEC%(%' 
                                             OR ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%WHILE%'
                                             OR ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%CURSOR%'
```

This will - for sure - not be smart in any way, but you can add further conditions to get better hits...